# Adobe Flex: Images, and a spark list

Tags: image, actionscript-3, apache-flex, list, adobe

I am trying to display images in a spark list. I have tried A TON of methods and none of them seem to work. Here is my code:

```
 var list:List = new List();
list.width = 200;
list.height = 300;
list.labelField = "LabelName";

var array:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection;
array.addItem(new BitmapImage().source="/assets/appLogo.png");
array.addItem(new BitmapImage().source="/assets/companyLogo.png");

list.dataProvider = list;
```

The list displays on the screen, but the images do not appear in the list. Instead of the image in the row, it says "/assets/appLogo.png" in one row and "/assets/companyLogo.png" in the other row. I have spent a couple hours trying to solve this with no luck. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

These lines do not look right:

```
array.addItem(new BitmapImage().source="/assets/appLogo.png");
array.addItem(new BitmapImage().source="/assets/companyLogo.png");
```

What it appears to be doing is create a new BitMapImage and setting the source property on it.  Won't the item you are adding to the array be the results of the assignment?  Or--it sounds like you're getting--the actual source value.  If you want an array of BitMapImages you can create it like this:

```
var tempImage :BitMapImage = new BitmapImage()
tempImage.source="/assets/appLogo.png"
array.addItem(tempImage);
tempImage = new BitmapImage()
tempImage.source="/assets/companyLogo.png"
array.addItem(tempImage);
```

However a List will not know what to do with the BitmapImage unless you build a custom itemRenderer that knows how to display it:

```
<s:List dataProvider="array">
 <s:itemRenderer>
   <s:ItemRenderer dataChange="onDataChange()">
     <fx:Script>
       protected function onDataChange():void{
        this.removeChild(data); 
        this.addChild(data as BitMapImage);
       }
     </fx:Script>
   </s:ItemRenderer>
 </s:itemRenderer>
</s:List>
```

However, I suspect it will be more beneficial to have an array of Strings representing the source and then create the BitMapImage in the renderer.  There is no need to create lots of BitMapImage components if you aren't going to be using them all at once.  Sort of like this:

```
array.addItem("/assets/appLogo.png");
array.addItem("/assets/companyLogo.png");

<s:List dataProvider="array">
 <s:itemRenderer>
   <s:ItemRenderer dataChange="onDataChange()">
     <fx:Script>
       protected function onDataChange():void{
        this.bitMapImage = data;
       }
     </fx:Script>
     <s:BitMapImage id="bitMapImage" />
   </s:ItemRenderer>
 </s:itemRenderer>
</s:List>
```

Comment: Hi. While I am sure that your solution would work, I need to be able to create the ItemRenderer using AS3 because I am creating my list inside of a function method. Do you know of a way to do what you suggested above inside of a function method?

Comment: An itemRenderer is just a component, and you can't create an in-line component in ActionScript.  You can create the itemRenderer as a separate class; and then when you create your list set the itemRenderer property like this: list.itemRenderer = new ClassFatory(mycomponent);

Comment: So I should create a class tha is like this? `package views
{
 public class ListImages
 {
  public function ListImages()
  {
   this.removeChild(data);
   this.addChild(data as BitmapImage);
  }
 }
}`

Comment: The easiest route is going to be to create an MXML class similar to what is between the s:itemRenderer tag in my sample.  The problem with your AS class is it doesn't extend ItemRenderer; doesn't make use of the Flex Component LifeCycle methods, and won't change update the BitMapImage when the data of the renderer changes.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you write a pure ActionScript renderer class which extends LabelItemRenderer which contains a private Image object, then override set data() and create and load the image if it doesn't exist and just load it if it does.

The data you pass into the list should just be a set of strings with image file url paths, then use that as the .source attribute for the image.

You can then override layoutContents to position and scale the image based on the size of the list row.

I've done this, but I don't have a super simple clean example to post at present.  If you still don't get it let me know and I'll upload some code.

Comment: Just for clarity, LabelItemRenderer is only usable in mobile projects. It's not a class you can extend if you're making a web application. And since the OP is referring to images, the IconItemRenderer (also mobile only) would be a better choice. IconItemRenderer also does some caching of images.